# Get unique values in table by multiple criteria

Tags: sql

My table is :

Table 1

```
ID     Payment_type       Time
A           X           2014 01
A           Y           2014 08
B           X           2013 10
A           Y           2014 08
B           Z           2013 09
A           Y           2012 01
A           Z           2014 08
```

And Results should be

```
ID     Payment_type     
A           Y           
B           X
```

The requirement is first look at the max time for an ID. If there is only 1 observation, then get the corresponding value for payment type. If there is more than 1 row for max time for an ID, get the payment type which occurs the most (in case of tie, pick any value).

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also tell What is the datatype of `Time` column ?

Comment: data type of time is 'bigint'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this question, you need to frequency of each value at each time:

```
select id, payment_type, time, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by id, payment_type, time;
```

Next, you need to choose the maximum value for each `id` based on time and then `cnt`.  The simplest method uses `row_number()`:

```
select id, payment_type, time
from (select id, payment_type, time, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc, cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, payment_type, time
     ) ipt
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input !